# Generic method with a generic interface

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to create a generic method where the type is a generic interface.

```
private void ShowView<T>(string viewName) where T : IView<Screen>
{ 
    IRegion mainRegion = _regionManager.Regions[RegionNames.MainRegion];
    T view = (T)mainRegion.GetView(viewName);
    if (view == null)
    {
        view = _container.Resolve<T>();
        mainRegion.Add(view, viewName);
    }
    mainRegion.Activate(view);
    view.LoadData();
    view.ViewModel.IsActive = true;
}
```

Interface is `IView<T> where T : Screen`.

So I have `ConcreteView : IView<ConcreteViewModel>` and `ConcreteViewModel : Screen` where Screen is the base class. When I try to do `ShowView<ConcreteView>("concrete");` I get an UnknownMethod error.

Is it because ConcreteView uses ConcreteViewModel instead of Screen for it's IView implementation? Is there a way to rewrite the method so that it works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IView<ConcreteViewModel>` is not an `IView<Screen>` without providing variance to the interface

```
interface IView<out T>
{
}
```

(The above can be done starting in C# 4.0)

Otherwise, you should be able to write your method signature like below

```
void ShowView<T, U>(string viewName) where T : IView<U> where U : Screen
{
     // code
}
```

And invoke it like `ShowView<ConcreteView, ConcreteViewModel>("blah");`

Comment: This is, because every generic interface is treated as a different one. Since .NET4.0 covariance is possible and so you could use the out statement.

Comment: OK. I had tried it without specifying `<T, U>` and kept getting an error. Thanks...that's what I was missing.